# Test for nil values presence in Dictionary

Tags: swift, validation, dictionary

I have the following Dictionary:

```
["oct": nil, 
 "jan": Optional(3666.0), 
 "nov": nil, 
 "apr": nil, 
 "sep": nil, 
 "feb": nil, 
 "jul": nil, 
 "mar": nil, 
 "dec": nil, 
 "may": nil, 
 "jun": nil, 
 "aug": nil]
```

I want to enable a button only when any value of any key is not nil. Is there any functional "magics" to do it without a traditional loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`contains(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905153-contains) on the dictionary values:

```
// Enable button if at least one value is not nil:
button.isEnabled = dict.values.contains(where: { $0 != nil })
```

Or

```
// Enable button if no value is nil:
button.isEnabled = !dict.values.contains(where: { $0 == nil })
```

Comment: In the second case (my case) I get the warning "Comparing non-optional value of type '(key: String, value: Any?)' to nil always returns false". Why?

Comment: @3000: I tested it with `let dict = ["oct": nil, "jan": Optional(3666.0) /* ... */ ]` defined as in your question, and that compiles. – Did you accidentally type `dict.contains` instead of `dict.values.contains` ?

Comment: Ok, now I understand: I forgot 'values' because I get the dictionary this way: `self.form.values()` (it's a method call in a 3rd party library), so the full code would be `!self.form.values().values.contains(where: { $0 == nil })`, with a repeating 'values' (thanks for pointing me in the right direction)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905694-filter) to check if any value is nil in a dictionary.

```
button.isEnabled = dict.filter { $1 == nil }.isEmpty
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already been provided with similar solutions, but here you go:

```
dict.filter({$0.value == nil}).count != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to conform to the standard dictionary definition that a `nil` value indicates *no key* and declare the dictionary non-optional (`[String:Double]`).

In this case the button will be enabled if all 12 keys are present. This is more efficient than `filter` or `contains`

```
button.isEnabled = dict.count == 12
```

Comment: This was my very first try but I'm not sure I can change the dictionary itself (it's the result of a method call in a 3rd party library and it produces an array with nil keys)

Comment: Assigning a `nil` value to a dictionary with non-optional values removes the key. That's the normal behavior.

Comment: I don't know what the library does at a low-level, but if I print the array, without inserting any value (except for the one you see), I get keys with nil values